# How to display total number of rows in FooTable?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, footable

I am pushing data into FooTable via Ajax. I refresh all rows on each AJAX call by using this code,

```
$('.footable tbody').html(outData[1]).trigger('footable_redraw');
```

I want to show total number of rows in the table, as well as start and end rows in the current page in footer area.

For example,

View 1-30 of 90631 Products

I checked documentation of FooTable, but didn't found anything relevant.

I got the total number of length by using this code,

```
$("tbody tr").length
```

How can I get start and end row numbers as I am using pagination in Footable?

Comment: could you post the html DOM structure as well, also if possible could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count number of tr (*which means row*) tags in your table body :

```
$("tbody tr").length
```

Here example : http://jsfiddle.net/RomanGroovyDev/5Ntye/18/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It worked for me. I also want start and end rows number of that page as I am using pagination in FooTable.